# Magnolia to Magento interface

Tags: magento, magnolia

Is there any solution or documentation for an interface between Magnolia CMS and Magento?
I really have no idea where to start:

- should it rely on Magnolia Rest API
- or be standalone app reading and writing from/to both datasources
- or modules/plugins on both platforms listening to each other

Any thoughts or links would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download [this](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/product/connectors.html) or look at [this](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/E-commerce+module#E-commercemodule-Magentoconnectionconfigurationandimplementation).